# $_SESSION value always empty

Tags: php, session

I conditionally embed one of two headers on a given page: either "Companies", or "Students and Professionals".

I store the user's type ('', 'student', or 'professional') in the `$_SESSION` array on login, then use a simple if statement to determine which header to embed.

The conditional (if) statement doesn't seem to work though; the first always evaluates as `TRUE` and `company_home_header.php` is always included, even when I've previously set `$_SESSION['usertype']` to `'student'` or `'professional'`.

Why isn't the string stored in `$_SESSION['usertype']` being evaluating correctly?

```
<?php

if ($_SESSION['usertype'] == "")
{
    include('includes/company_home_header.php'); 
}
elseif ($_SESSION['usertype'] == "student" OR 
        $_SESSION['usertype'] == "professional")
{
    include('includes/home_header.php'); 
}

?>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **`session_start()`** on the top of your PHP code.

```
<?php
    session_start();//<---Here
    if($_SESSION['usertype'] == ""){
        include('includes/company_home_header.php'); 
}
    elseif($_SESSION['usertype'] == "student" || $_SESSION['usertype'] == "professional") {
        include('includes/home_header.php'); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Also note, `($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'student' or 'professional')` isn't testing what you think it is.  (It checks the truthiness on either side of the `or` -- and `'professional'` is always truthy, so the `or` will always return true if you get to that point.)  You need to test against both values individually.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, use `session_start()` and your expression is not correct:

```
elseif($_SESSION['usertype'] == "student" || $_SESSION['usertype'] == "professional") {
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
<?php
        session_start();

       if($_SESSION['usertype'] == ""){
            include('includes/company_home_header.php'); 
    }
        elseif($_SESSION['usertype'] == "student" or "professional") {
            include('includes/home_header.php'); 
    }
    ?>
```